# jquery: make item in parent window draggable from within iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, draggable

I have an issue with making an element in a parent window draggable. Im trying to make it draggable from within an iframe. There is not really a workaround, i.e. I cannot include jquery in the parent window.

I wrote a very simple test code so I could rule out issues with the website itself but I got the same problem. I ll copy it for you for better understanding:

[outside.html]

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="draggable" style="background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);width: 400px; height: 300px;">
    <iframe id="i" src="inner.html" style="width: 390px; height: 290px; margin-top: 6px;"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
```

[inside.html]

```
<html>
<head><title></title>

<script language="JavaScript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="jquery.ui.selectmenu.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="slides.min.jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

      // Make div container draggable

    $('#draggable', window.parent.document).draggable({

    });

});

</script>

</head>

<body>
inner
</body>
</html>
```

Thats it. What happens is that the div doesnt really become draggable. When I click it it just kind of jumps around randomly. When I let the mouse go and try to drag it again nothing happens to it at all.
Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be? 
Thank you!